# mBED has time complexity $O(n \lg n)$, claimed by Clustal Omega paper, why?

Tags: sequence-alignment

In the [Clustal Omega paper](https://www.embopress.org/doi/full/10.1038/Msb.2011.75), it says the following about mBED ($N$ is the number of input sequences, I assume):

> we use a modified version of mBed (Blackshields et al , 2010), which has complexity of $O(N \log N)$

But in the [mBED paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/1748-7188-5-21) it says the following (section 2):

> A number of $t$ sequences are initially sampled from the input dataset $X .$ Following the LLR
> algorithm, this value is set by default to $t=\left(\log _{2} N\right)^{2} .$

> After the seed sequences in $R$ have been chosen, all sequences in the input data are associated with a $t$-dimensional vector. This is done simply by computing the distances from all sequences to each of the $t$ seeds.

Then my conclusion is that this would lead to a complexity of $O(N (\log N)^2)$ because for each  sequence (in total $N$ of them), distances to $t = (\log N)^2$ sequences must be calculated. Where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I was dumb: I misread.

The Clustal Omega paper (in the supplementary materials) chose $t = \log N$, which I think originates from this claim from this part of the Linial et al. paper:

> In random polynomial time $X$ may be embedded in $l_{2}^{O(\log n)}$ with distortion $\leq(1+\epsilon) \cdot c_{2}(X)$ (for any $\epsilon>0)$

Several questions still remain though:

1. The newest implementation of Clustal Omega (that I downloaded) has source code that instead chooses $t = (\log N)^2$, why changed?
2. The original mBED paper chooses $t = (\log N)^2$, but it was not justified on how they chose this number instead of $\log N$